# Django : Many to many relation in with a shared model between multiple apps

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a big project based on Django. I want to make a model (say root) which will be used in multiple apps. Every app will have a model having many to many relation with this root model. As per my knowledge, I have planned project structure like this:

App1/models.py

```
class Root(models.Model):
    #some fields

class M1(models.Model):
    roots = models.ManyToManyField(Root)
    #other fields
```

App2/models.py

```
from App1.models import Root

class M2(models.Model):
    roots = models.ManyToManyField(Root)
    #other fields
```

I want to know that is it okay ? Will I have any problems if I try to retrieve other app's model's objects in current app linked by this root model.
Also I want to get advice what cares should I take further as This is my first django project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what the purpose of this `Root`? if it just contain aditional fields for each model, you can create `AbstractModel` instead, and inherit from it

Comment: Thanks for attention. Root is for connecting M1 and M2 from different apps. I will have one object of M1. It is connected to some x1,x2,x3,..,xn objects of Root. I want to get all Objects of M2 who is connected to either of any x1,x2,x3,...xn. I know how to write query(or a set of queries). But I want to know will it affect badly further ? Will I face any trouble ? Regards from me.

Comment: I not sure, I understand full purpose, but in that case, unique table  created for each `M1` and `M2` models with link to `Root`, if you want all link in one place, you should put it in `Root`. But I'm still don't sure it is right choice